# Is $O(f(n)\cdot g(n)) = f(n)\cdot O(g(n))$?

Tags: asymptotics

Prove or disprove with counter example:
$$O(f(n)\cdot g(n)) = f(n)\cdot O(g(n))$$

Attempt:
$f(n) = x^2 + x + 1$
$g(n) = x^3$
L.H.S. = $x^5$
R.H.S. = $(x^2 + x + 1)x^3$
L.H.S. $\neq$ R.H.S.

Am i correct?

Comment: This is a property of Big-O notation, listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Product).

Comment: Can you tell me what i did wrong in my example?

Comment: @kayush The $O$ notation doesn't denote exact functions, but rather an order of magnitude. Thus, for example, $O\left(f\left(x\right)\right) = O\left(g\left(x\right)\right)$ doesn't necessarily mean that $f\left(x\right) = g\left(x\right)$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan i know, have i used this anywhere in my attempt?

Comment: @kayush Yes, you did implicitly in your statement for R.H.S. The value of $O\left(g\left(x\right)\right)$ is not necessarily $g\left(x\right) = x^3$.

Comment: Thanks, but how to approach such problems?

Comment: per definition. it is an equality between sets. so for the first direction let h(x) be in O(f*g). that means h(x) <= c*f(x)*g(x). we have to show that h is in f*O(g) rearranging leads to h(x) <= f(x)*(c*g(x)), so h is in f*O(g). i guess you can see the second direction out of this one.